# Create an API endpoint capable of accepting POST requests from a webhook in Java

Tags: java, json, webhooks

I have a webhook setup where, after an upload, a notification is sent by the file server to the Webhook Tester URL, using HTTP POST. In the webhook config file, Webhook Tester URL is assigned as the endpoint. For example, when a file called `image1.jpg` is uploaded to a bucket named `images` in a minio server, I get a JSON data like this in the Webhook Tester's endpoint:

```
{
"EventName": "s3:ObjectCreated:Put",
"Key": "images/image1.jpg",
"Records": [
{
  "eventVersion": "2.0",
  "eventSource": "minio:s3",
  "awsRegion": "",
  "eventTime": "2018-10-16T05:53:23Z",
  "eventName": "s3:ObjectCreated:Put",
  "userIdentity": {
    "principalId": "EZXTCHKE2YHUNRPI8JCL"
  },
  "requestParameters": {
    "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "responseElements": {
    "x-amz-request-id": "155E00FBBE5DC52B",
    "x-minio-origin-endpoint": "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
  },
  "s3": {
    "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
    "configurationId": "Config",
    "bucket": {
      "name": "images",
      "ownerIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EZXTCHKE2YHUNRPI8JCL"
      },
      "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::images"
    },
    "object": {
      "key": "image1.jpg",
      "size": 374960,
      "eTag": "eeee5654de91dd9295590449405b4a2c",
      "contentType": "image/jpeg",
      "userMetadata": {
        "content-type": "image/jpeg"
      },
      "versionId": "1",
      "sequencer": "155E00FBBE5DC52B"
    }
  },
  "source": {
    "host": "",
    "port": "",
    "userAgent": "Minio (linux; amd64) minio-go/v6.0.6 mc/2018-09-26T00:42:43Z"
  }
}
]
}
```

How can I implement something like this in jax-rs? How can I create an API endpoint that is capable of handling POST requests, similar to Webhook Tester that'd produce JSON data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by creating a POST resource handler like this:

```
@POST
@Path("webhook")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response webhookListener(NotificationConfiguration nc) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(nc);
    System.out.println(jsonString);
    return Response.ok().entity(jsonString).build();
}
```

`NotificationConfiguration` is the data type using which minio server sends the webhook notifications, and using jackson, I converted `NotificationConfiguration` to JSON, thus achieving the desired JSON data.